# Flask Many Pagination on One Single Page using flask-paginate 0.4.5

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, multiple-instances, pagination

[image]I want to render three paginations on one single page using flask-paginate.
The problem is that the three paginations are "synchronized" in te sense that clicking 'Next Page' of one pagination affects the other pagination too.
I have tried to use different page names for different pagination but there is still something missing.
I haven't found NOTHING about the Multiple Pagination, please help me in solving this issue. 
PLEASE TAKE A LOOK AT THE PICTURE ATTACHED TO BETTER UNDERSTAND.
Please note that I have followed the Miguel Gringberg book in creating this application, but he considers just single paginations and not multiple. https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world

I have a page ''discover.html'' with 3 lists of paginated elements:

```
<div class="discover-content">

        <div class="contests-list">
            {% with projects=contests, pagination=contests_pagination, page='main.discover', fragment='#contests' %}
                <h2>Most Recent Contests</h2>
                {% include '_contests.html' %}
            {% endwith %}
        </div>

        <div class="skills-list">
            {% with skills=skills, pagination=skills_pagination, page='main.discover', fragment='#skills' %}
                <h2>Skills</h2>
                {% include '_skills.html' %}
            {% endwith %}
        </div>

        <div class="ideas-list">
            {% with projects=ideas, pagination=ideas_pagination, page='main.discover', fragment='#ideas' %}
                <h2>Most Recent Ideas</h2>
                {% include '_ideas.html' %}
            {% endwith %}
        </div>

</div>
```

Where each list is like the following ''_skills.html'':

```
{% import "_macros.html" as macros %}

<ul class="skills">
    {% for skill in skills %}
        {% if skill.name %}
        <li class="skill">{{ skill.name }}</li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

{% if pagination %}
    <div class="pagination">
        {{ macros.pagination_widget(pagination, page, fragment=fragment) }}
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

The file ''_macros.html'' works in this way:

```
{% macro pagination_widget(pagination, endpoint, fragment='') %}
<ul class="pagination">
    <li{% if not pagination.has_prev %} class="disabled"{% endif %}>
        <a href="{% if pagination.has_prev %}{{ url_for(endpoint, page=pagination.prev_num, **kwargs) }}{{ fragment }}{% else %}#{% endif %}">
            &laquo;
        </a>
    </li>
    {% for p in pagination.iter_pages() %}
        {% if p %}
            {% if p == pagination.page %}
            <li class="active">
                <a href="{{ url_for(endpoint, page = p, **kwargs) }}{{ fragment }}">{{ p }}</a>
            </li>
            {% else %}
            <li>
                <a href="{{ url_for(endpoint, page = p, **kwargs) }}{{ fragment }}">{{ p }}</a>
            </li>
            {% endif %}
        {% else %}
        <li class="disabled"><a href="#">&hellip;</a></li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    <li{% if not pagination.has_next %} class="disabled"{% endif %}>
        <a href="{% if pagination.has_next %}{{ url_for(endpoint, page=pagination.next_num, **kwargs) }}{{ fragment }}{% else %}#{% endif %}">
            &raquo;
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
{% endmacro %}
```

The view associated to the page ''discover.html'' is the following:

```
@main.route('/discover', defaults={'page_c': 1, 'page_i': 1, 'page_s': 1}, methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@main.route('/discover/page_c/<int:page_c>/page_i/<int:page_i>/page_s/<int:page_s>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def discover(page_c, page_i, page_s):

    contests_page = request.args.get(page_c, 1, type=int)
    contests_pagination = Project.query.filter_by(project_type='contest').order_by(Project.timestamp.desc()).paginate(
        contests_page, per_page=current_app.config['CONTESTS_PER_PAGE'], error_out=False)
    contests = contests_pagination.items

    ideas_page = request.args.get(page_i, 1, type=int)
    ideas_pagination = Project.query.filter_by(project_type='idea').order_by(Project.timestamp.desc()).paginate(
        ideas_page, per_page=current_app.config['IDEAS_PER_PAGE'], error_out=False)
    ideas = ideas_pagination.items

    skills_page = request.args.get(page_s, 1, type=int)
    skills_pagination = Skill.query.order_by(Skill.name.desc()).paginate(
        skills_page, per_page=current_app.config['SKILLS_PER_PAGE'], error_out=False)
    skills = skills_pagination.items


    return render_template('discover.html', contests=contests, ideas=ideas, skills=skills,
                           contests_pagination=contests_pagination, ideas_pagination=ideas_pagination,
                           skills_pagination=skills_pagination)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most clear way to handle this is with asynchronous requests (Ajax). You would have three separate endpoints for your three lists of items, each paginated individually. The main HTML page will issue Ajax requests to these three endpoints, and moving between pages in one list should not affect the other two lists at all.

If you want to keep doing it as a single page with the three lists in it, then you have to make sure the pagination links in all your lists include the correct page numbers for all three lists. For example, if you are viewing pages 1, 2 and 3 respectively on these three lists, and you hit next page on the second list, that next page link should be going to `/discover/page_c/1/page_i/3/page_s/3`, so that the first and third lists stay on their pages 1 and 3, and the second list moves from page 2 to page 3. You will need much more complexity in your macro, it needs to know the page numbers of the three lists, and which of the lists is changing.